# LINQ Join/Grouping issues

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

So I am stuck again...

I have three tables that I am trying to join and group with linq; Company, Notices and Requests.

- A company could have many notices.
- A notice have a SubcategoryId and a CompanyId
- A request have a SubcategoryId.

My aim here is to get a list of companies and for each company get a list of their noticed subcategories and for each noticed subcategory the requests within that subcategory

**Ex:**
Company x is monitoring the subcategories 4 and 7.
Show him what requests we've got within those subcats.

This is how I do it for only one company. But I can't solve the grouping and joins when I need a list of multiple companies.

```
Company company = db.Companies.Where(x=>x.UserId == 10).FirstOrDefault();
            var requestByNotices =
            from notice in company.Notices
            join request in db.Requests.Where(z => z.IsApproved &
                 z.Status.Status == "Active") on notice.SubcategoryId equals
                 request.Subcategoryid
```

**UPDATE**

Let me rephrase my questions.

This query is producing a table with the results I am looking for:

```
SELECT Companies.CompanyId, Companies.Name, Account.Email, Notices.SubcategoryId, Requests.FriendlyName FROM Companies
INNER JOIN Notices  ON Companies.CompanyId = Notices.CompanyId 
INNER JOIN Account  ON Account.UserId = Companies.Uid
INNER JOIN Requests ON Notices.SubcategoryId = Requests.Subcategoryid 
WHERE Requests.StartDate > '2013-12-22';
```

But instead of generating a flat list I would like to translate this into to linq but also group by CompanyId. So each company is represented by one row only and within that company I can get the requests.

So instead of a list like this:

```
CompanyId   Name   Email            SubcategoryId     FriendlyName
1           Test   test@test.com    2                 x
1           Test   test@test.com    4                 y
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
CompanyId   Name   Email            GroupOfRequests  
1           Test   test@test.com    contains two
```

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** if i understand right you want something like this

```
var result =
        from company in db.Companies
        from notice in company.Notices
        join request in db.Requests.Where(z => z.IsApproved &&
             z.Status.Status == "Active") on notice.SubcategoryId equals request.Subcategoryid
        group new {notice, request } by company into gr           
        select new {gr.Key, Value = gr.ToList() }
```

**UPDATE2**
for your sql it seems like this

```
from company in db.Companies
join notice in db.Notices on company.CompanyId equals notice.CompanyId
join account in db.Account on company.Uid equals account.UserId
join request in db.Requests on notice.SubcategoryId equals request.SubcategoryId

group new {notice, request} by new {company, account} into g
select new {g.Key, value = g}
```

Comment: Hmm I am trying to build on this but it doesn't work. gg.Any() is generating an error and if I remove it I get one row per company and notice-subcategory.

Comment: Wow, thanks alot! It worked if I removed the .ToList() from gr.
Is it easy to left join the account table with the company table to get email together with company name?

Comment: now in Key object you have company - so you can get name, email, etc from it

Comment: Yes, but email is in a fourth table(Account) that I would like to join with company :) 

See my updated question above...I manage to join and group it into gr but it would make more sense to join it in company

Comment: Grundy, if i was to return a ViewModel out of this, how would that model be designed? :)

Comment: @Josef, possibly better create another question. Anyway you can create class of you ViewModel instead of anonymous class